# Getting error while running datastax intsallation runner in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, datastax, datastax-enterprise

When I tried to run the **DataStaxEnterprise-5.1.8-linux-x64-installer.run**in my linux machine, it shows throws below error

> There has been an error.
>   Upgrades from package/system installs are only possible as root user.
>   The application will exit now.

Can someone help me with this. Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

You're running it with insufficient privileges - you need to run it using `sudo` command as described in the [DSE Admin Guide](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/install/installGUIdse.html).   From message I see that you may have already DSE installed, and need admin rights to upgrade the system.

Comment: Fixed the issue. I deleted an existing installed one which was lying inside /usr/local. Thank you Alex